# Is SCEP safe if I use a different long and complex password per enrollment, and validate it against expected parameters?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, mobile, ios, scep

I'm considering [using SCEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Certificate_Enrollment_Protocol) to enroll iPads and other devices in my network.  The iOS configuration profile allows me to configure a different password for each device.

Is it valid, and safe for me to issue many different SCEP passwords, and upon submission of the request, that a server-side process cross-references that password against a predefined set of expected parameters... where any deviation of the EKU for example would cause an issuance failure.

Are there any other considerations I should address with SCEP?  (besides password length for the above solution?

Answer (score 1):

SCEP has been standardized at last and the RFC includes a lengthy [security considerations section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8894.html#name-security-considerations).

The main takes with regards to passwords are

> The challengePassword, despite its name, shouldn't be a conventional password but a high-entropy shared-secret authentication string. Using the base64 encoding of a keying value generated or exchanged as part of standard device authentication protocols like the Extensible Authentication Protocol (EAP) or DNP3 Secure Authentication (DNP3-SA) makes for a good challengePassword. The use of high-entropy shared secrets is particularly important when the PasswordRecipientInfo option is used to encrypt SCEP messages; see Section 3.1.

> If feasible, the challengePassword should be a one-time value used to authenticate the issue of a single certificate (subsequent certificate requests will be authenticated by being signed with the initial certificate). If the challengePassword is single use, then the arrival of subsequent requests using the same challengePassword can then be used to indicate a security breach.
> The lifetime of a challengePassword can be limited, so that it can be used during initial device provisioning but will have expired at a later date if an attacker manages to compromise the challengePassword value -- for example, by compromising the device that it's stored in.

> The CA should take appropriate measures to protect the challengePassword. Examples of possible measures include: physical security measures; storing it as a salted iterated hash or equivalent memory-hard function; storing it as a keyed MAC value if it's not being used for encryption; and storing it in encrypted form if it is being used for encryption.